# How to use Popup control to show a view?

Tags: c#, wpf, popup

I need to show a view on a click of a button. This is the code for the event `Click`

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Button s = sender as Button;
    //some stuff needed to recognise which button was pressed
    myPopup.PlacementTarget = s;
    myPopup.Placement = System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.PlacementMode.Top;
    myPopup.IsOpen = true;
}
```

this is the element defined in xaml

```
<Popup IsOpen="False" StaysOpen="True" Name="myPopup">
       <view:myCustomView />
</Popup>
```

I have 2 problem with this.

1- The background of my view is black, even if i didn't set it (i think it should be transparent?)

2- When i click anywhere inside the Popup, this simply disappear

Which is the proper way to show my view? I don't want to bind anything of the `ViewModel` that own the button to this new view, which has his own viewmodel

Note that on the event `Button_Click` i will send some parameters to the `ViewModel` of `myCustomView` that will change some of its functionality (that's why i need to create a new instance of the view every time the `Button_Click` event is fired)

EDIT 1: Thanks to the answer of EdPlunkett i was able to solve the problem with the background. I just need to set AllowsTransparency="True"

EDIT2:

I defined my `Popup` via Code Behind as suggested, so my code now is:

```
  private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Button s = sender as Button;
            System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.Popup popup = new System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.Popup();
            popup.AllowsTransparency = true;
            popup.Child = new myCustomView();
            popup.PlacementTarget = s;
            popup.Placement = System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.PlacementMode.Top;
            popup.IsOpen = true;
            popup.StaysOpen = true;
        }
```

The problem is, that when i click inside any of the controls defined inside myCustomView, the Popup lose the focus and close.

Comment: `myPopup` is not defined anywhere ... do you mean `pippup` instead?

Comment: @ Fruchtzwerg yes, i'm sorry i edited the name and forgot that one.

Comment: Add `AllowsTransparency="True"` to the `Popup` element.

Comment: StaysOpen is already set true ... are you sure the popup closes after you clicked anywhere?

Comment: @Fruchtzwerg i don't know if it close or if simply disappear. Surely i canno't see it anymore. It would be great if i could lock the UI while the Popup is Opened

Comment: @EdPlunkett that solved the problem of the black background thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect that the `Popup` is defined inside another `Popup` like for example the dropdown of a `ComboBox`, right?

You could try to create the `Popup` element programmatically in the click event handler:

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Button s = sender as Button;
    System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.Popup popup = new System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.Popup();
    popup.AllowsTransparency = true;
    popup.Child = new myCustomView();
    //some stuff needed to recognise which button was pressed
    popup.PlacementTarget = s;
    popup.Placement = System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.PlacementMode.Top;
    popup.IsOpen = true;
    popup.StaysOpen = true;
}
```

This should let you click within the pop up view without the `Popup` being closed. Make sure that the view has a `Background` set:

```
popup.Child = new myCustomView() { Background = Brushes.White };
```

> I tried your solution, and while it's true that the situation is slightly better, i still have the closing problem. I can click inside the Popup without this being closed, but when i click inside any of the textbox that i defined inside my view, the Popup close

So set the `PlacementTarget` to the parent `ItemsControl` and then set the `VerticalOffset` and `HorizontalOffset` properties of the `Popup` to specify its exact location on the screen, e.g.:

```
private void btn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Button s = sender as Button;
    System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.Popup popup = new System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.Popup();
    popup.AllowsTransparency = true;
    popup.Child = new myCustomView();
    //some stuff needed to recognise which button was pressed
    popup.PlacementTarget = ic; //<-- "ic" is the name of the parent ItemsControl
    Point p = s.TranslatePoint(new Point(0, 0), ic);
    popup.VerticalOffset = p.Y;
    popup.HorizontalOffset = p.X;
    popup.IsOpen = true;
    popup.StaysOpen = true;
}
```

You should adjust the values of the `VerticalOffset` and `HorizontalOffset` to fit your requirements.

Comment: He could define the Popup in the XAML outside the other popup, too, and just use it as he's doing, couldn't he?

Comment: Yes, probably, as long as it is not located in another Popup. But since he is handling the Click event he might as well create the Popup when the Button is actually clicked. It's one way or the other :)

Comment: Unfortunately i'm not at work and i can't replicate your suggestion. I will give update monday. However, what i can say is that my Popup was not defined inside another popup but inside an ItemsControl, and more precisely, the button that should trigger this popup is included inside a combobox defined within this ItemControl template. I don't know if it's the same thing.

Comment: Plus, after EdPlunkett suggestion, with transperent background, i could have noticed that: The view is shown above all the rest, but my focus is still on the underlying view. I saw this, because i can move my mouse inside the dropdown of a combobox highlighting its elements

Comment: I tried your solution, and while it's true that the situation is slightly better, i still have the closing problem. I can click inside the Popup without this being closed, but when i click inside any of the textbox that i defined inside my view, the Popup close.

Comment: Set the PlacementTarget to the ItemsControl then. See my edited answer. It should give you the idea.